# Is it possible to run custom actions during uninstall using InstallShield 2009

Tags: installation, action, installshield

I need to run a custom action during uninstallation of a ManagedCode which is a part of the installation (Before it is removed in the uninstall process)
Is it possible in Install Shield 2009?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can run a ManagedCode custom action as part of the uninstall.  You just need to sequences it in the Install Exec Sequence with a condition of `REMOVE="ALL"`.  InstallShield is just a wrapper around Microsoft's MSI technology, so many times it is best to go the MSDN for help understanding what you want to do.  For example this entry should help you schedule your action, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371626(VS.85).aspx

Comment: As far as the ordering of the custom action is concerned, it can be placed after system defined `Install Files` action. This *should be* the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my IntallShield Express 11 I can have Custom Actions in Uninstall in several different places.